# How to tell if a tab is website or just an image?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension that checks if a tab is an image or a website. Let me elaborate: I want to inject (or execute) some code only if the tab is an image, for example, if the tab URL is:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/MorningIndianRiver%2C_KennedySpaceCenter.jpg

So if I make a background script that checks if URLs are of images (`*.jpg` for example), then it will execute the code for everything that looks like an image but it doesn't, like this for example:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MorningIndianRiver,_KennedySpaceCenter.jpg

which looks like an URL for an image but it isn't. And the problem is that sometimes the tab is actually an image even if there is no extension extension, like this:

http://placehold.it/500x500

which is an image, but the background script doesn't know that.

So how to tell if a tab is an image or a website? Is there something in the API that handles this?

Comment: Use/inject a content script that checks if the only body element is an image, its src being equal to the tab URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm Probably a better solution than mine, but idk how reliable that could be across different versions of chrome

Comment: @Hatchet Agree! It was changed just this weekend! So it's not something to take for granted!

Comment: Not sure how the browser version may affect this. I've been using [Center Image](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/110-center-image) userscript that utilizes the said method for many years, seems reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `HEAD` request to the resource in question and read the `Content-Type` response header. You'll probably have to make cross origin requests, though, but if you're developing a Chrome extension, [looks like there's a permission for that](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).

You'll probably be looking for MIME types that match `image/*`.

Comment: But the request will be asynchronous. How would I adapt to that!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir That's the beauty of xhr, that it's async. Take a look at the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest, add a readystatechange handler, or open it synchronously, there are a lot of different ways to use it.

Comment: I know that the beauty of XHRs is their asynchronous nature. But in this case I want to redirect to a local page if the tab is an image (the function should return immediately not wait for XHR to be done). I can do it by creating another local page that does the XHR and see if it's an image or not then either redirect to my local page or to the original website, but then if it was website it'll be looping all day (website > backgrounds script > the local page that does the XHR > website > backgrou...)..

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir you can force the request to be synchronous with the third parameter of the open() method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

Comment: That was deprecated I believe!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Of course it is; it's *supposed* to be used asynchronously. If you wish to use this solution with XHR, I'd still recommend refactoring your codebase to accommodate the asynchronous request.

Comment: Yeah I think that's what I'm going to do! I'll accept this answer because it provided me with what I want!